# Maven: Report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-project-info-reports-plugin has an empty version

Tags: maven, maven-2

I have a Maven 2 project which I build with the following parameters:

```
-B -f <path to pom.xml> clean site -P <several profiles>
```

I see the following warning message in the build log:

```
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default) @ autotest ---
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Jenkins\workspace\selfTests\${localProfile}
[INFO] [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.

[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default) @ autotest ---
[INFO] Copying 29 resources
[WARNING] Report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-project-info-reports-plugin has     an empty version.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[INFO] configuring report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Relativizing decoration links with respect to project URL: http://maven.apache.org
[INFO] Rendering site with org.apache.maven.skins:maven-default-skin:jar:1.0 skin.
[INFO] Generating "Cobertura Test Coverage" report    --- cobertura-maven-plugin:2.6
[INFO] Cobertura 2.0.3 - GNU GPL License (NO WARRANTY) - See COPYRIGHT file
```

The part of the pom.xml section with `org.apache.maven.plugins`:

```
...
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>resources</goal>
                        <goal>testResources</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <filesets>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>src/main/generated-groovy-stubs</directory>
                    </fileset>
                </filesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
        </plugin>
        ...
```

I tried to explicitly include in the `dependencies` section:

```
...
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>
...
```

But it did not resolve my issue. I still see the warning message in the log.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Include info for the `maven-project-info-reports-plugin` in the `plugin` section (where for example also the `maven-resources-plugin` is specified):

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>resources</goal>
                        <goal>testResources</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <filesets>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>src/main/generated-groovy-stubs</directory>
                    </fileset>
                </filesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: note that this is in the `<plugins>` list which is contained under the `<reporting>` element

Answer (score 0):

I'd the error but resolved, after deleting

/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins

and running

```
man clean package site
```