# check of pom.xml to be compliant with mvn site command for github pages

Tags: maven, github-pages, maven-site-plugin

When trying to publish my open source projects to gh-pages with

```
mvn site
```

there have been lots of obstacles recently due to changes in the way maven and github pages works.

After studying

- https://help.github.com/articles/creating-project-pages-using-the-command-line/
- https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/
- https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/

Here are some of the needed prerequisites i found and issues i ran into:

**prerequisites**

1. git branch needs to show a gh-pages branch e.g. after using the commands in https://gist.github.com/ramnathv/2227408
2. the version of the maven-site-plugin and the maven-project-info-reports-plugin have to be correct and correctly configured: [maven-site plugins 3.3 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.DocumentContent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51091539/maven-site-plugins-3-3-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-maven-)
3. dependency.locations.enabled property needs to be false [Why am I getting Maven error: "Unable to determine if resource X exists in http://maven.glassfish.org/content/groups/glassfish"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26144541/why-am-i-getting-maven-error-unable-to-determine-if-resource-x-exists-in-)

**issues**

- [How to force GitHub Pages build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24098792/how-to-force-github-pages-build)
- [Maven: Report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-project-info-reports-plugin has an empty version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734650/maven-report-plugin-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-project-info-reports-plugin)
- [Maven: What is pluginManagement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483180/maven-what-is-pluginmanagement)
- [Multi module POM - creating a site that works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848715/multi-module-pom-creating-a-site-that-works)
- [Struggling with Maven parent/child plugin configuration inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648556/struggling-with-maven-parent-child-plugin-configuration-inheritance)

not even mentioning work arounds i have to use for ssh-wagon and Java8 javadoc and others

The plugins used are IMHO a "moving target". Something that worked a few months ago in my experience will not work today. So I keep fixing my pom.xml files to keep up and the files grow longer and longer.

See e.g. https://github.com/BITPlan/com.bitplan.simplerest/blob/master/pom.xml

For my internal projects I use a parent pom to make sure that the projects have a common configuration. For the open source projects I did not find a way to use a parent pom for a group of projects yet.

I would like to make sure that a working configuration that i found is "transferred" to other configurations. I am thinking e.g. of

1. a script that might check the configuration
2. some kind of inheritance mechanism like the parent pom

I assume this is a pretty common problem and there are experiences by SO users on how to tackle this issue accross different project.

**What would be a good approach and what tools would be useful?**

1. parent pom with pom packaging
   [What is "pom" packaging in maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692161/what-is-pom-packaging-in-maven)  mostly states the use of pom packaging for multi-module projects but it looks it could be used to have a reference for a parent pom. The parentPath defaults to .. see [Maven: Non-resolvable parent POM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612309/maven-non-resolvable-parent-pom). The overriding of configurations is explained in [Maven : Is it possible to override the configuration of a plugin already defined for a profile in a parent POM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771561/maven-is-it-possible-to-override-the-configuration-of-a-plugin-already-defined)

**Examples for moving targets**

- Java8 silly javadoc settings

  - [Maven is not working in Java 8 when Javadoc tags are incomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886209/maven-is-not-working-in-java-8-when-javadoc-tags-are-incomplete)
  - [How to disable Javadoc warnings in Maven Javadoc Plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39616344/how-to-disable-javadoc-warnings-in-maven-javadoc-plugin)

Comment: If you are using ssh-wagon for github pages you are doing something wrong..can you please show a link to your project? Best would be to use [Maven SCM Publish plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-scm-publish-plugin/) See also the docs about: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-scm-publish-plugin/various-tips.html#Git_branch

Comment: BTW: If you have several open source project why not creating a parent project yourself ? Like I did https://github.com/khmarbaise/smpp ? And then you can use that parent....

Comment: The think you wrote: `The plugins used are IMHO a "moving target". Something that worked a few months ago in my ...` have you defined all used plugins in your pom file with their appropriate versions? This is the only situation which explains your sentence?

Comment: @khmarbaise - thx for looking into this. I have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [khmarbaise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296328/khmarbaise) there is now a [common parent pom](https://github.com/BITPlan/com.bitplan.pom/blob/master/pom.xml) in place.

```
mvn site
```

can be run [for all projects using this parent pom](https://github.com/BITPlan/com.bitplan.pom/blob/master/docs/BITPlanOSProjects.md) with a common set of reports and the result will be transmitted to the corresponding github pages.

A projects specific pom can now [be as short as just 25 lines](https://github.com/BITPlan/com.bitplan.simplerest-api/blob/master/pom.xml)

I am now actually in the process of creating a check script for the pom files and a generate script for the README.md files. This is one of the useful snippets:

usage example:

```
checkghpages https://github.com/BITPlan com.bitplan.simplerest
```

**Check that the gh-pages exist and create after asking**

```sh
#
# check the github pages for the given project
# 
# param 1: base url in github
# param 2: project name/directory
#
checkghpages() {
  local l_baseurl="$1"
  local l_project="$2"
  cd $ws/$l_project
  git ls-remote --heads | grep gh-pages > /dev/null
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]
  then
    color_msg $red "github pages branch gh-pages missing for $l_project"
    color_msg $blue "shall i create the branch gh-pages for $l_project?"
    read answer
    case $answer in
      y|Y|yes|Yes|j|Ja) 
        color_msg $blue "creating gh-pages branch for $l_project ..."
        cd /tmp
        # https://gist.github.com/ramnathv/2227408
        git clone $l_baseurl/$l_project
        cd $l_project
        git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/gh-pages
        rm .git/index
        git clean -fdx
        echo "<a href='$l_baseurl/$l_project'>Initial GitHub Page for $l_project</a>" > index.html
        git add .
        git commit -a -m "First pages commit by checkos script"
        git push origin gh-pages
        cd $ws/$l_project
        git pull
      ;;
    esac
  else
    color_msg $green "github pages branch gh-pages for $l_project exists✓"
  fi
}
```